# Consecutively animate array of UIViews with Swift

Tags: ios, animation, recursion, uiview, map-function

I have an array of views (`UIStackView.arrangedSubviews`) which I want to animate with `UIView.animate()`. But I only want to start animating the next element, when the previous one is finished.

I want to find a somewhat "elegant" solution to this. I have tried two different approaches, but I'm stuck on both of them. How can I achieve this?

### First attempt: Recursive closure

```
let animate = { (views: [UIView]) -> () in
    guard let view = views.first else { return }
    UIView.animate(
        withDuration: 0.5,
        animations: {
            view.frame.origin.y -= 30.0
            view.alpha = 1.0
    },
        completion: { finished in
            if finished {
                // TODO: Only start animating next view when previous is finished?
                animate(views.removeFirst()) // ERROR: Variable used within itself
            }
    })
}
```

### Second attempt: Using array map

```
let _ = stackView.arrangedSubviews.map { view -> UIView in
    view.frame.origin.y += 30.0
    UIView.animate(
        withDuration: 0.5,
        animations: {
            view.frame.origin.y -= 30.0
            view.alpha = 1.0
        },
        completion: { finished in
            // TODO: Only start animating next view when previous is finished?
    })

    return view
}
```

Comment: Did my updated answer work?

Answer (score 3):

How about just enumerate them, and animate them not using `completion`, but using a `delay` parameter? You can calculate delay for the `i`th view as `i * animDuration`:

```
let animDuration = 0.5
for (index, view) in stackView.arrangedSubviews.enumerated() {
    view.frame.origin.y += 30.0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: animDuration, delay: animDuration * Double(index), options: [.curveLinear], animations: {
        view.alpha = 1
        view.frame.origin.y -= 30.0
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

P.S.: Just as a side note, `UIStackView` uses auto layout to layout its arranged subviews. Be careful about setting their frames directly.

**EDIT**

Although I think that you can be pretty sure that using the `delay` would work as you expected, you can try chaining the animations using `UIViewPropertyAnimator` objects:

```
var animators: [UIViewPropertyAnimator] = []
stackView.arrangedSubviews.forEach({ (view) in
    let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.5, timingParameters: UICubicTimingParameters(animationCurve: .linear))
    view.frame.origin.y += 30.0
    animator.addAnimations {
        view.alpha = 1
        view.frame.origin.y -= 30.0
    }
    // start this animator in completion of the previous one (if there is previous one)
    let previousAnimator = animators.last
    previousAnimator?.addCompletion({ (_) in
        animator.startAnimation()
    })

    // append new animator to animators
    animators.append(animator)
})

// now you should be able to run the chain by starting the first animator
animators.first?.startAnimation()
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I have thought about it, but I would prefer to trigger the next from the completion block, as then it is 100% sure that the previous is finished animating. This is a solution, but not the most preferred one in my view.

Comment: About your PS note, do you have a suggestion about how i should rather do it?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you want to achieve, but I usually just set `view.isHidden` to `true` to make it hidden, and then to `false` when animating it to its place. But that may not be the same effect you want to achieve.

Comment: The views are fading in and sliding up at the same time. But good to know that this is something to look into.

Comment: @eivindml take a look at the updated answer. Haven't tested it, so that will be your task :)